# How to use hover css with circle image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to use hover css with circle image ?

I want ,When cursor into black circle image, it's will be change red circle image ?

But in my code when cursor into div black circle image will be change red circle image

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grxe655m/)

```css
.test {
  background: url(http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/iw/151029115044.png);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.test:hover {
  background: url(http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/it/151029115107.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

But if css can not do that , how can i do this with javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

### Pure CSS

I'm not too sue the question is explained very well. But for just changing a black circle to a red circle, you don't need images.

```css
.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.circle:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#linkhere" class="circle"></a>
```

### CSS With Image

If you do want to retain your images, then you just need to add `border-radius: 50%` to your current code.

```css
.test {
  background: url(http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/iw/151029115044.png);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.test:hover {
  background: url(http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/it/151029115107.png);
}
```

```html
<a href="#linkhere" class="test"></a>
```

Comment: You can either do it with an `<a>` element which surrounds the div but ive changed my example above to use the `a` element as the actual circle which requires using `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `border-radius:50%` on the `div`

```css
.test{
    background: url(http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/iw/151029115044.png);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.test:hover{
    background: url(http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/it/151029115107.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Warning about cursor on Safari

---

If you are using ***img*** element, you will notice that on Safari, cursor appears outside of circle and also hover effect applies when cursor reaches the square of image, not the circle. But this doesn't happen on Chrome.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1);
}
div.outer-inline-box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.circle {
  background-color: rgba(210, 210, 210, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.circle:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-inline-box">
  <img class="circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"/>
</div>
<div class="outer-inline-box">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```